# Retrofit BodyObservable: when null value slips into RxJava2 NPE is not propagated to onError()

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

When the response came with empty body, Retrofit BodyObservable calls onNext() with null value. In RxJava2 that leads to NPE, but that is not an issue, and there's a recommended way to deal with it using Completable or Optional converter (https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2242).

The problem I have encountered that in some scenarios onError() handler is not triggered at all, so that observable silently fails when getting NPE (making it harder to spot and fix). I've managed to isolate this case:

```
data class Item(val name: String)

class Retrofit2WithRxJava2TestCase {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    public val server: MockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    interface Service {
        @GET("/{path}")
        fun getItem(
            @Path(value = "path", encoded = true) path: String?
        ): Observable<Item>

        @DELETE("/{path}")
        fun deleteItem(
            @Path(value = "path", encoded = true) path: String?
        ): Observable<Item>
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun test() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(server.url("/"))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val example = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

        server.enqueue(
            okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/json")
                .setBody("""{"name": "Name"}""")
        )
        server.enqueue(
            okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(204)
        )

        val observable: Observable<Item> = example.getItem("hello")
        val observable2: Observable<Item> = example.deleteItem("hello")

        val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
        disposable = observable
            .flatMap {
                observable2
                    //.doOnError { // <- This one would be triggered
                    //    println("doOnError triggered")
                    //}
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally { // <- Never reaches here
                countDownLatch.countDown()
                println("doFinally")
            }
            .subscribe({ next ->
                println("onNext")
            }, { error ->  // <- Never reaches here
                println("onError $error")
            })

        val result = countDownLatch.await(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        Assert.assertTrue(result)
    }
}
```

So, the question is why the NPE is not propagated to onError() in this case, when observable2 inside .flatMap{} gets empty body, and hence triggers onNext() with null value?

Thank you for all suggestions.

EDIT:

Simplifying test observable to make sure unit test thread won't exit before observable completion:

```
observable.flatMap {
                //Observable.error<Throwable>(NullPointerException()) //<- Would reach onError()
                observable2
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
            .doFinally { // <- Never reaches here
                println("doFinally")
            }
            .blockingSubscribe({ next ->
                println("onNext")
            }, { error ->  // <- Never reaches here
                println("onError $error")
            })
```

Comment: May I ask why you are flatmapping into the same Observable? I don't think that `flatMap` is needed there at all.

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly sorry, that was a typo, I have corrected the source, it should read 'observable.flatMap{observable2}'.

Comment: Can you use a `blockingSubscribe` in there instead of `subscribe` with a `CountDownLatch` and remove the Schedulers to see if it still happens?

Comment: Changing to blockingSubscribe() and removing the Schedulers did not change the behaviour.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you just throw `Observable.error<Throwable>(NullPointerException())` inside the `flatMap`?

Comment: How can you say that "It never triggers a specific error" if you throw the stream into completely different threads? Please try it with `Schedulers.trampoline()` instead of `io` and `mainThread`. This will make sure that the stream runs in the same thread as the unit test. If not, then the unit thread might exit before the stream has a chance to even reach `onError`. Let us know after.

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly throwing error like you mentioned, inside flatmap, actually I've tried it before, and in this case error gets propagated to onError().
This seems like a threading issue anyway, I'll experiment a little further.

Comment: @Fred Thank you, I've made the changes that you've suggested and the onError() was triggered. However, it doesn't seem like the problem is in unit test exiting before the observable stream, as I can put a latch without the timeout to exhibit the same problem. 

Could you please look at edited sample?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. So you've just proven that with a null pointer exception you reach `onError`. I've just tried your edit sample in pure kotlin and replaced `observable2` with `Observable.just(345).flatMap { Observable.just(null) }` and I also reach `onError`. Why is this behaviour not expected or not working for you?

Comment: Yes this is expected and correct behaviour, and your sample also works for me. There seems to be some subtle difference with observable2, that's covered by Retrofit's BodyObservable and doesn't propagate the error.

Comment: did you try adding the logging interceptor to see if the body is actually null?

Comment: @Fred, kind of, I have landed a breakpoint in retrofit BodyObservable, so I'm sure that it's being converted to null. Also I have started a thread in git Retrofit issues here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3437